# To read a file,which one will be faster?using fstream,FILE* or memory mapping?

Tags: c++, file, stream, memory-mapping

Here is my project configuration：vs2013,win32,Debug.

I want to know for different file sizes,which of the 3 file reading methods will be faster.They are c++ style fstream,c style file read and write and memory mapping.

But after execution,here is my result:

> File Size 1225284
>   fstream time 47
>   c file pointer time 0
>   memory mapping time 0
>
> File Size 14856192
>   fstream time 15
>   c file pointer time 0
>   memory mapping time 47
>
> File Size 97198080
>   fstream time 16
>   c file pointer time 0
>   memory mapping time 265
>
> File Size 1259530844
>   fstream time 31
>   c file pointer time 16
>   memory mapping time 11138

It seems that for stream and FILE* reading,the time needed to read a file won't increase as the file size increases.But for memory mapping,that's true.This phenomenon is pretty odd.
Because in my opinion,for large files, memory mapping will faster.
Here is my code:

```
string ifile = "M:/Thesis/FileReadCmp/1.txt";
string os = "M:/Thesis/FileReadCmp/new_cmp1.txt";
int page_size = 2 * 1024 * 64 * 1024;//128M
for (int j = 0; j < 100; ++j){
    os[os.size() - 5] = '1' + j;
    ofstream o(os);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
        ifile[ifile.size() - 5] = '1' + i;
        ifstream in(ifile);

        in.seekg(0, ios::end);
        o << "File Size " << in.tellg() << endl;
        o << endl;
        in.close();

        //using fstream to read file
        long long st = GetTickCount();
        in.open(ifile);
        char c;
        while (in >> c){
            ;
        }
        in.close();             
        long long et = GetTickCount();
        o << "fstream time " << et - st << endl;

        //using FILE* to read file
        st = GetTickCount();
        FILE* cpf = fopen(ifile.c_str(), "r");
        char cc = fgetc(cpf);
        while (cc != EOF)
        {
            cc = fgetc(cpf);
        }
        fclose(cpf);
        et = GetTickCount();
        o << "c file pointer time " << et - st << endl;

        //using memory mapping to read file
        const char* pc = ifile.c_str();
        st = GetTickCount();
        HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(pc, GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, 0,
            NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        int file_size = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
        HANDLE hFileMap = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, FALSE,
            TEXT("SharedData"));

        if (hFileMap == NULL){
            // if no such object,create a file mapping object
            hFileMap = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE,
                0, 0, TEXT("SharedData"));
        }

            int rem_file_size = file_size;
            int offset = 0;
            while (rem_file_size > page_size){
                PVOID pvFileView = MapViewOfFile(hFileMap, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, offset, page_size);
                char* asc_dex = (char*)pvFileView;
                for (int i = 0; i < page_size; ++i){//, c = 0++c
                    char c = asc_dex[i];
                }
                //UnmapViewOfFile(pvFileView);
                offset += page_size;
                rem_file_size -= page_size;
            }
            PVOID pvFileView = MapViewOfFile(hFileMap, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, offset, rem_file_size);
            char* asc_dex = (char*)pvFileView;
            for (int i = 0; i < rem_file_size; ++i){//, c = 0++c
                char c = asc_dex[i];
            }
            UnmapViewOfFile(pvFileView);

        CloseHandle(hFileMap);
        CloseHandle(hFile);

        et = GetTickCount();
        o << "memory mapping time " << et - st << endl;
        o << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you mapping every page separately?

Comment: Because for files as large as 1GB, I can't map the file as a whole.what confused me most is the reading speed using stream and FILE*@immibis

Comment: I have deleted the UnmapViewOfFile(pvFileView); inside the cycle.@immibis

Comment: Whoops, I didn't notice you had 128MB pages - I was assuming page_size was the size of a page (which is only 4kB). With 128MB "pages", the overhead from mapping each one shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I think `UnmapViewOfFile` should be inside the loop; otherwise it's a leak, isn't it?

Comment: Yes,I agree.But the time spent by memory mapping soars.About several hundred times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105859/discussion-between-yuan-wen-and-immibis).

Comment: How are you accounting for cache effects?  Reading the same file multiple times in a row most likely means all but the first read comes from cache unless the file is too large to be cached - but even then caching will impact the result.  And what about simple POSIX-style `read()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be the open mode.The default open mode of memory mapping is binary.

When I changed `in.open(ifile);` to `in.open(ifile, ios::binary);`;`FILE* cpf = fopen(ifile.c_str(), "r");` to `FILE* cpf = fopen(ifile.c_str(), "rb");`The real running times of 3 methods become in accordance with theory.They are as follows:

> File Size 1225284
>   fstream time 297
>   c file pointer time 93
>   memory mapping time 0
>
> File Size 14856192
>   fstream time 3167
>   c file pointer time 1045
>   memory mapping time 47
>
> File Size 97198080
>   fstream time 20779
>   c file pointer time 6833
>   memory mapping time 281
>
> File Size 1259530844
>   fstream time 268696
>   c file pointer time 88406
>   memory mapping time 11216

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient method is to keep the input stream flowing.  Usually, this means reading in large blocks of data (more data per request).

One method is to have multiple buffers (search the internet for "double buffering") and multiple threads.

The reading thread will read and fill up one buffer, then signal that data is ready.  The reading thread moves on to fill up the next buffer.

The processing thread (which was waiting on the reading signal) wakes up and starts processing the buffer, then outputs the data.

One objective is to use as many large buffers to adjust the speed of reading data versus the processing speed.  Again, the idea is that the reading of data is continuous with regards to processing.

Comment: Your advice is good.But for the 3 file read/write methods?For different type of files,Which one will be better if I don't use the method you mentioned above?@Thomas Matthews

Comment: When reading data from a file, the file type does not matter.  You want to input the data then analyze (parse) the data.  Opening and reading the data may be faster than using memory mapping.  The memory mapping depends on the OS and the OS may need to perform context switches or paging to accommodate the request.  When you read the file yourself, you can manage when to read and the amount of memory allocated.